# Print pairs of elements in a list that have the same average value as the list's average value

Tags: python, list, printing, average

I wrote a simple code to calculate a list's average value.

```
import statistics

x = [5, 6, 7, 0, 3, 1, 7]
print(round(statistics.mean(x)))

>>>> 4
```

How do I get it to print the pairs that have the same average value? For example, [1, 7] has the same average value as 4.

Answer (score 0):

Pairwise iteration

```
for a, b in itertools.product(x, x):
    if (a + b) / 2 == average:
        print(a, b)
```

Comment: It could be done in linear time, with two iterators on a sorted list.

Comment: that's less iterations, but still O(N^2)

Comment: No, that can be linear. You have one loop and it advances the iterator going from the beginning OR the iterator going from the end, depending on whether the sum is too low or too high, until the iterators meet.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
import random
while True:
    lst = random.sample(range(15), random.randint(2,10)) 
    if sum(lst)/len(lst) == 4:
        print(lst)
```

NB: This method could create duplicate lists.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from itertools import permutations, combinations
>>> l = [5, 6, 7, 0, 3, 1, 7] 
# compute average
>>> avg = sum(l)//len(l) 
# generate all possible combinations
>>> [i for i in combinations(l, 2)] 
[(5, 6), (5, 7), (5, 0), (5, 3), (5, 1), (5, 7), (6, 7), (6, 0), (6, 3), (6, 1), (6, 7), (7, 0), (7, 3), (7, 1), (7, 7), (0, 3), (0, 1), (0, 7), (3, 1), (3, 7), (1, 7)]
>>> [(a+b)//2 for a,b in combinations(l, 2)] 
[5, 6, 2, 4, 3, 6, 6, 3, 4, 3, 6, 3, 5, 4, 7, 1, 0, 3, 2, 5, 4]
# only filter those which average to the mean of the whole list
>>> [(a,b) for a,b in combinations(l, 2) if (a+b)//2==avg]  
[(5, 3), (6, 3), (7, 1), (1, 7)]
```

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension together with `itertools.combinations` will come handy here. Since you are comparing 2 float numbers, it is useful to use a threshold deciding whether the 2 numbers are close enough that are considered equal (so we are being careful with floating point errors!)

```
from itertools import combinations
import numpy as np

def close(p, q, eps): # Use to compare if 2 float values are closer than epsilon
    return np.abs(p - q) <= eps

l = [5, 6, 7, 0, 3, 1, 7]
my_mean = np.round(np.mean(l)) # 4.0
a = [(x, y) for (x, y) in combinations(l, 2) if close(np.mean([x,y]), my_mean, 0.1)]

print(a) # [(5, 3), (7, 1), (1, 7)]
```